# Can't run the prepare.py script on linphone-android project

Tags: android-studio, cmake, linphone

I want to build linphone for android on android studio,

I follow the guide on https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android,

but on **step 3**, I keep getting exception:

> CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to
>   "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need
>   to select a different build tool. CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not
>   set, after EnableLanguage CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set,
>   after EnableLanguage
>   -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Did I miss any setting on cMake?  I just wanna make it work on android studio.

Comment: The error message tells that CMake cannot find make. Have you `make` installed?

Comment: just install the cmake-3.5.2-win32-x86.msi file, and add the system path.
http://tudat.tudelft.nl/projects/tudat/wiki/Install_on_Windows

Comment: `cmake` and `make` are **different** packages, installing one of them doesn't install another.

Comment: Thanks for your help~ I installed the make package, but now I got new exception about "Cannot find ndk-build".  but I already downloaded android-NDK and added it to the system path.

Comment: I also try to build the linphone library by cygwin, but It will change the system path to /cygdrive/c/, it will cause CMake missing the directory of "cmake-builder" folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update my final solution:

Those make/build libraries all from **Linux** kernel, so I finally giving up to build linphone on Windows and it works like a charm on Linux.